# Под зОнтом/зонтОм.

Tags: фонетика

На какой слог правильно делать ударение?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Зонт / зонтА / зонтУ / зонтОм / о зонтЕ

Answer (score 0):

Употребление "под зОнтом" появилось из арготизма - блатного присловья "с пОнтом под зОнтом", где ударение намеренно изменено ради созвучия. Нормативно - под зонтОм.